# Extract all substrings in a string following specific character not just first?

Tags: mysql, locate

I am able to extract substrings from a table where text follows a specific character e.g. "*":

`Select substring(FieldX,(Locate('*',FieklX)), 10) from Tqble where Fieldx like '%*%`'

This will give me the **first** match from each record in the table where "*" is found.  However I want **ALL** matches in each record where a * is found. Is there a way to specify this?

Comment: Is the maximum number of occurrences known?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Not per se but I could set up a theoretical limit of say 10 and be happy with it.